# PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: cannot extract element from a scalar

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I'm fetching data from the JSON column by using the following query.

```
SELECT id FROM ( SELECT id,JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(shipment_lot::json) AS js2 FROM file_table WHERE ('shipment_lot') = ('shipment_lot') ) q WHERE js2->> 'invoice_number' LIKE  ('%" abc1123"%')
```

My Postgresql version is 9.3

Saved data in JSON column:

```
[{ "id"=>2981, "lot_number"=>1, "activate"=>true, "invoice_number"=>"abc1123", "price"=>378.0}]
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  cannot extract element from a scalar:
SELECT id FROM 
  ( SELECT id,JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(shipment_lot::json) 
    AS js2 FROM file_heaps 
    WHERE ('shipment_lot') = ('shipment_lot') ) q 
WHERE js2->> 'invoice_number' LIKE  ('%abc1123%'))
```

How I can solve this issue.

Comment: Thats not valid JSON, thats probably your issue. I would recommend using a jsonb column instead, you can just insert a hash and rails will convert it on insert/select to a hash

Comment: Actually, this code was working till yesterday with the same dataset.  So I highly need to go with the same query.

Comment: Thats impossible, thats not JSON it could never be casted with `::json`

Comment: As you can see, I just need "id" from the mentioned query

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have improper JSON stored

If you try running your example data on postgres it will not run

```
SELECT ('[{ "id"=>2981, "lot_number"=>1, "activate"=>true, "invoice_number"=>"abc1123", "price"=>378.0}]')::json
```

This is the JSON formatted correctly:

```
SELECT ('[{ "id":2981, "lot_number":1, "activate":true, "invoice_number":"abc1123", "price":378.0}]')::json
```